# what could be the problem if a lawn mower not start completely for Craftsman Lawn Mower Model #247377440

Tags: lawn-mower

https://youtu.be/uV5H3kOkVfg detail video here!

additional detail, I replaced the red power starter key, original one broke in half, and I did accidentally put engine oil in gas tank, and I drained all or almost all by heaving it tilted almost upside down for an hour or more ....

more info about the law mower is here.
https://www.searspartsdirect.com/model-number/247377440/0247/1500600.html

https://www.sears.com/craftsman-21inch-front-wheel-drive-163cc-mower/p-07137744000P

Would like to know any hint.

Thanks

Comment: Always tip your mower to the opposite side of the oil inlet.  Otherwise you will get oil clogging everything up.  If you've an oil inlet, input...whatever on the right side of the engine, you tip your piece of equipment to the left. Ugh, I think, check this info!  Use your repair shop people and their knowledge every time you use them!  They will love you.  I learned so much by kissing butts of the repair shop dudes!  They put me up to be taken care of first and I had to have stuff fixed to continue my job!  These guys are wonderful and they taught me how to keep my stuff running FOREVER.

Comment: Wait a second...you put oil in the gas accidentally?  Is this a 2 stroke engine that needs 2 stroke engine oil added to the gas?  Was there oil already added to the gasoline? (btw, always use gasoline WITHOUT ethanol)!

Comment: @stormy I actually no idea what does 2 stroke engine means... I added more info on the question though, hope that can help you understand the situation more? since you sounds really like an expert (a lot more expert) than me for sure. let me know if they helps

Comment: @stormy and I did tilt the mower to the left where the oil tank was (where i accidentally put the engine oil in, and let it stay in there for about half hour until I realized I did the wrong thing....

Comment: 2 stroke engine needs to have oil added to the gasoline (non ethanol).  I looked at your cool video and I am now uncertain about my statement.  Your mower I would tilt to the right but not all the way upside down.  This mower will last forever if you learn how to keep the dirt out of it.  I would take this to the repair guys and act as if you are a total newbie with lots of money and lots of friends.  I happened to be a CUTE gal and I used that to get educated by these guys!  Most mowers are 2 stroke versus 4 stroke and higher engines.  Gasoline has to be mixed at 50:1 ratio for most 2 strokes

Comment: @stormy oh boy... what if I just sell it to someone (of course, let the person know this situation), its $400 retail with tax its 430 ish here. How much should I sell it for if you know this stuff better? thank you so much for replying with so much detail!

Comment: @Ezeewei This is truly not a deal breaker.  You have not ruined your engine.  When you learn a bit more about these engines you will appreciate them oh so very much more.  The oil did not ruin your engine.  Take it to the repair dudes and then learn from them how to do simple maintenance, replacing filters, how to tune the engine via those 2 screws; one is air and one is fuel?  Become the master of your tools!  Grins!  You can do this!

Comment: @stormy thank you so much for the encouragement! let me look into those things at the meantime for sure!

Comment: Your mower is pretty cool looking at the specs!  You can raise the deck to 3.75"?  Smart on Craftsman's part!  You are able to change out filters, clean the carb (using ethanol in your gas, ugh), check for spark, replace spark plugs (have a few on hand always as well as gas and air filters).  Getting the repair guys on your side is worthwhile.  They know this.  They also know they will always have a job, check out the back up of equipment waiting to be fixed!  When you schmooze them they will love you and teach you and gee, you won't need them.  This is a great little mower.

Answer (score 1):

In all reality unless you have some experience working with 2-strokes or small engines your best bet would be to find a very cheap mechanic or friend who can:

- Clean/replace air filter
- Clean the carburetor
- Clean/replace the oil filter
- Check for spark
- Check for compression
- Check the belt

If you dumped engine oil into the gas tank without trying to start it then you might be fine just cleaning the gas tank and the carb. If you tried to start it then you have a whole mess on your hands and you might be better of just buying a new mower.

Personally, I do not have a lot of experience with mechanical issues but I made a suggestion that this topic be moved in to a more appropriate section of stack overflow. There is an entire wing dedicated to mechanical issues such as these.

Comment: Yet, part of 'gardening' is the use of tools.  Tools are integral to gardening and I believe this information is totally pertinent.

Comment: @stormy That's a stretch and you seem to be contradicting yourself because you told the OP to "Take it to the repair dudes and then learn from them how to do simple maintenance". There is a virtual version of "the repair dudes" here on stack overflow you can find them here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com

Comment: stormy and Rob thanks you all the recommendations, both of you provided extremely valuable advises. Its good to know though, that, the mechanics SE is not just for cars, because I saw its for "...DIY enthusiast owners of cars, trucks, and motorcycles...." so I was hesitating to post my stuff there lol guess I should try that as well!

Comment: @Ezeewel That's where I would go if I were you. Bunch of gear heads over there and they know there stuff.